# how to detect if a word is underlined in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, spell-checking

I have made a form in a jsp page and applied spellcheck attribute of HTML5 to check for the incorrect words being entered by the user.
Now, the problem is that I have to make sure that the data entered by the user is not transferred until and unless all the spellings are correct.

For this there should be some kind of validation on misspelled words.

Please help me out, my jsp page code is given below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="topic">
    <div class="inputholder">
      <h1>Enter the text</h1>
      <form action="preprocessing" method="post" name="initialpage" onsubmit="return validateSpellcheck()">
        <textarea id="styleid" name="field3" placeholder="Here..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="hello" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is really restrictive, they would likely be unable to enter their own name for example

Comment: I generell it is a bad idea to rely on validation made on the the client since form data can be spoofed, so I would do that on serverside